# How to silence DataMapper in Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

So, a simple little question.  Every time I perform some transaction with DataMapper inside one of my "get" or "post" blocks, I get output looking something like this...

```
core.local - - [19/Sep/2012:09:04:54 CEST] "GET /eval_workpiece/state?id=24 HTTP/1.1" 200 4
- -> /eval_workpiece/state?id=24
```

It's a little too verbose for my liking.  Can I turn this feedback off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut off all logging:

```rb
DataMapper.logger = nil
```

To change verbosity:

```rb
DataMapper.logger.set_log(logger, :warn) # where logger is Sinatra's logging object
```

Other levels are `:fatal => 7, :error => 6, :warn => 4, :info => 3, :debug => 0` (http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-core/1.1.0/DataMapper/Logger)

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t Datamapper logging, this is the logging done by the WEBrick server, which [logs all requests using these two formats by default](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_286/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb#L54-59).

(Note this *isn’t* Rack logging either, although the Rack::CommonLogger uses the same (or at least very similar) format).

The simplest way to stop this would be to switch to another server that doesn’t add its own logging, such as Thin.

If you want to continue using WEBrick, you’ll need to find a way to pass options to it from your Sinatra app. The current released Sinatra gem (1.3.3) doesn’t allow an easy way to do this, but the [current master allows you to set the `:server_options` setting which Sinatra will then pass on](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/38f71248f839b95f6d17747a2c177bdd83f95f78/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1408-1409). So in the future you should be able to do this:

```ruby
set :server_settings, {:AccessLog => []}
```

in order to silence WEBrick.

For the time being you can add something like this to the end of your app file (I’m assuming you’re launching your app with something like `ruby my_app_file.rb`):

```ruby
disable :run
Sinatra::Application.run! do |server|
  server.config[:AccessLog] = []
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running with ActiveSupport, you can use the Kernel extension:

```
quietly { perform_a_noisy_task }
```

This temporarily binds STDOUT and SDTERR to /dev/null for the duration of the block.  Since you may not want to suppress *all* output, theoretically you can do:

```
with_warnings(:warn) { # or :fatal or :error or :info or :debug
  perform_a_noisy_task
}
```

and appropriate messages will be suppressed.  (NB: I say *'theoretically'* because using `with_warnings` gave me a seemingly unrelated error in my Padrino/DataMapper environment.  YMMV.)